# Inability to run MAMP

Tags: mamp

I installed MAMP 5.0 on my Windows 10 Pro of recent. The installation ran smoothly, however, it is taking a long time to launch whenever I click on Start Server. Does it require internet connection to run? How do I bypass this long delay in having the Apache and MySQL servers ticked?
I tried connecting to the internet, perhaps to facilitate quick access, yet the effort seems abortive.
Please, I am in need of assistance. Thanks

Comment: Is your MAMP not running at all or just running slow?